# Pandas exporting to Excel (xls, xlsx) with multilevel columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want collect few tables into the one with pandas. I use the code presented below:

```python
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import types

df = None
for frame in ['x', 'y']:
    df_ = pd.read_excel(u'%s.xlsx' % frame)
    df_ = df_.set_index([u'time'])

    parameters = list(df_.columns)
    tuples = []
    for tup in itertools.product([frame,], parameters):
        tuples.append(tup)

    columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=[u'Frames',u'Parameters'])

    df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=df_.index)
    for par in parameters:
        df_new[frame, par] = df_[par]
    del df_

    if df is None:
        df = df_new
    else:
        df = pd.concat([df, df_new], axis=1)

df.to_excel('merged_xlsx.xlsx')
df.to_excel('merged_xls.xls')
```

Source data is `x.xlsx`

[image: x.xlsx]

and `y.xlsx` files.

[image: y.xlsx]

XLS engine works well (`merged_xls.xls`):

[image: merged_xls.xls]

But something is wrong (cells merging) with XLSX engine (`merged_xlsx.xlsx`):

[image: merged_xlsx.xlsx]

Manual cells unmerging works in Excel:

[image: merged_xlsx_unmerged.xlsx]

Is it bug in XLSX pandas engine (openpyxl)? Or what is wrong in my code?

Versions: `python-2.7.10`, `pandas-0.17.0`, `openpyxl-2.3.0`

Comment: looks like a bug, please file an issue on github :) https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues

Comment: Issue https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11408 is closed with bug fixes.